# Are YouTube videos you upload posted to the connected Google+ account?

Tags: youtube, google-plus

I just started a new YouTube channel and I'm wondering if the videos you uploaded get posted to your Google+ account?

Basically I have my main Google/YouTube account and I went and created a new channel under the same account, which of course created it's own Google+ page.

Now, I have followers (peoples in my circles) on my main Google+ account and I **don't** want them to be notified I have uploaded a video.

I know the new channel has it's own profile page, but since they are connected under the same main account I wasn't sure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Google Plus was shutdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Google+ page (or a  Google Brand page) is basically a separate account as far as your audience is concerned. There are no public ties between your personal account and your page whatsoever.

If you are uploading a video, there may be a "share to twitter/Google+" box that you can tick or untick. If you leave them ticked, it'll share the video to the connected twitter account (as specified on https://www.youtube.com/account_sharing) and the Google+ page connected to the channel.